# Max and min of $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt[3]y} \log(\frac {5}{4} y^2+x^2-4x+4 )$ on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

$D$ = $\{(x,y): (x-2)^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1\}$. If I consider $f$ on $D$ I found: $g(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]y} \log(1+y^2)$.
the function g is crescent for $y\in (0,2]$ and decrescent  for $y\in [-2,0)$ so there is a max in y=2?
f is not continuous in D?

Comment: $g$ is strictly increasing on $[-2,2]$ (defining $g(0)=0$) because $\sqrt[3]{y} < 0$ for $y < 0$.  Thus the unique maximum of $g$ is indeed at $y=2$ and the unique minimum at $y=-2$.